# Sum of all nodes from A to B in a Tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

Given a Tree and pointers to two of it's nodes A and B (a key value of each node is positive).

Find an algorithm that sums up all the values on the path between A and B,
when preproccessing is allowed.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Preproccessing: $O(n)$

For each node in the tree, we will keep the sum of all the values on the path from the root to the node.

Additionally, we will prepare for [LCA (lowest common ancestor)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) queries in $O(n)$ time.

### Query: $O(1)$

When asking for the sum on the path $A \rightarrow B$,
Return $$\text{sumFromRoot}(A) + \text{sumFromRoot}(B) - 2 \cdot \text{sumFromRoot}(\text{LCA(A,B)})$$

We subtract twice the path from the LCA to the root, as we counted it twice in the sums from the root.